# Drop Select List onmouseover go to up

Tags: html

```
 <select name="sometext" 
    onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
    onmouseout="this.size=1"
    onchange="this.size=1">
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>

</select>
```

This select list works, but I want the options go up and not down!

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. AFAIK, the browser handles this. For example, if your `select` is at the bottom of a page, and there isn't room for the options to expand below, the browser will expand them upward instead.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<select size="2" style="visibility:hidden;width:1px;max-width:10px;">
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>
</select>
<select name="sometext" 
    onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
    onmouseout="this.size=1"
    onchange="this.size=1">
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pv20hw8L/